# Closing emacs results in "Current desktop was not loaded from a file" even though desktop-save-mode was set before start

Tags: desktop

I have set the following things in my .el file (not init.el):

```
(setq desktop-dirname         "~/.emacs.d/desktop/"
  desktop-base-file-name      "emacs.desktop"
  desktop-base-lock-name      "lock"
  desktop-path                (list desktop-dirname)
  desktop-save                t
  desktop-files-not-to-save   "^$" ;reload tramp paths
  desktop-load-locked-desktop nil
  desktop-auto-save-timeout   30)

(desktop-save-mode 1)
```

Although the desktop file is saved/updated to `~/.emacs.d/desktop` the following happens. When I try to close emacs I get the following message:

> "Current desktop was not loaded from a file. Overwrite this desktop
> file?"

Even if I choose to overwrite it (and close emacs), the exact same thing happens the next time closing emacs.

Comment: Is that all there is to the recipe to repro the problem? Do you see the same thing if you start Emacs using `emacs -Q` (no init file) and you then use that code? Seems like we're missing some info.

Comment: Probably a noob question but if I start emacs without an init file, how should I test the issue?

Comment: Start Emacs without an init file, then do whatever you would do in your init file that's needed to repro the problem - and only that stuff (no extra stuff from your init file). Tell us step by step what you see and what you expected to see instead.

Comment: I don't get it... There are 3 options: 
-I either have all the options set like in my post and get the message and it does not work correctly  
-I don't set them just (desktop-save-mode 1) and I get prompted every single time where I want to save my desktop
-I disable desktop saving. 
I don't even do anything else just edit my .el file (which is then read by init.el) and that's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the result of not including (desktop-read) in your setup.

DON'T DO ONLY THIS:

```
(desktop-save-mode 1)
```

But rather do both of these:

```
(desktop-save-mode 1)
(desktop-read)
```

(desktop-read) is the thing that "reads current desktop from a file".